# Ionic application http post request get fails and gives 403?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```js
   

     loginUser: function (name, pw) {
            return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
              var authdata = ' Basic ' + window.btoa(name + ':' + pw);
    //encode Base64
              var reqUrl = URL_CONSTANTS.baseUrl+'/login'
              var methodType = 'POST'
              var reqHeaders = {
                  'Authorization': authdata}
              var reqData = {}
      //request to proceed
              var req = {
                method: methodType,
                url: reqUrl,
                headers: reqHeaders,
                data:reqData
              }
             //makes hit to the server and get's the response
             $http(req).success(function (response, status, headers, config) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: 'common success',
                  template: JSON.stringify(response) + " >> " + JSON.stringify(status)+ " >> " + JSON.stringify(headers) + " >> " + JSON.stringify(config) 
                });
                resolve(response);
              }).error(function (error, status, headers, config) {
                $ionicPopup.alert({
                  title: 'error',
                  template: JSON.stringify(error) + " >> " + JSON.stringify(status)+ " >> " + JSON.stringify(headers) + " >> " + JSON.stringify(config)
                });
                reject(error);
              });              
            });
    }
```

```html
 <button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="loginUser('user','password')">Login</button>
```

> every time i call this method gets 403 ,can you tell me what is wrong in my code or what am i missing, i have used the cordova whitelist also but its not working.
>
> this is the link of the snap shot of the response which i was getting https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRzLw.png

Comment: Can you create live example for that so i can check it.

Comment: Currently working on live project so i can't share the more details like URL. It would be more helpful if you mention some scenarios  for which this type of error can occur.

Comment: My above code is working fine , the issue is from server side it may be CORS issue.

Answer (score 2):

just add the below code in your php backend server

```
 // Allow from any origin
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }
    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
        exit(0);
    }
```